# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in Express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mern

I'm getting this error while running this code. The API is running fine, after that it is throwing this error.

```
app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        channelTwo.consume(queue, async (data) => {
            if (data) {
                const _data = JSON.parse(data.content);
                const SavedData = new User(_data);
                await SavedData.save();
                channelTwo.ack(data);
                if (SavedData) {
                    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Date Saved to db', SavedData });
                }
                res.status(400).json({ message: 'Cant save data' });
            }
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'Cant find data' });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: error });
    }
})
```

;

Answer (score 0):

You have to return after calling `res.status(<>).json()` otherwise it will be called multiple times.
This will try to set a response header code although already json body has already been sent causing your error

Comment: Do we need to return every res.status().json() or the final one ?